# My Preloader with Overlay not working in Chrome ... Why?

Tags: css, asp.net

here is my css

```
.divWaiting{

position: absolute; 
background-color: #FAFAFA;
z-index: 2147483647;
opacity: 0.8;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center; top: 0; left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding-top:20%;
}
```

and here is my panel

```
 <asp:UpdateProgress ID="PreLoader" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="divWaiting">
                <asp:Image ID="preload" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/preloader.gif" />&nbsp
        Payment Processing ... Please wait
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

works fine and covers the entire screen in IE and Firefox, but in Chrome it just
takes up a small space at the bottom of the screen, as through it is part of the UI. I want it to be in the center and cover the whole screen but be able to see through to screen behind. What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you try to use Chrome development tool and play with element CSS?

Comment: Can you share your code in jsFiddle or codpen. so I can work around that

Comment: there is no problem here https://jsfiddle.net/3jqmg6jw/embedded/result/ you need to give the html code that asp produces

Comment: Paul, so does the answer below help?

Comment: no, nothing seems to be be working :( it works great in IE and Firefox and I have used this code before

Comment: post the full page html/css or share a full page demo if you want further help? right now, nothing i can do really.

Comment: well as it turns out .. it does work in Google Chrome, just not on my local drive, possibly because of the version I am working on. thanks for all of your help!!